# Only execute JS if the screen size is more than 1024px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar that becomes position:fixed when the bottom of the div is visible (followed this [tutorial](http://techbrij.com/fixed-sidebar-scrolling-jquery-div)). **My problem is I only need the JS to work if the screen size is more than or equal to 1025px.**

I know I need something along the lines of `if($(window).width() > 1025)`, but I can't figure out where that needs to be. I'm not great with JS so any help would be appreciated.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/30/)

JS

```
$(function () {

if ($('.leftsidebar').offset()!=null) {

    var top = $('.leftsidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('.leftsidebar').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var height = $('.leftsidebar').height();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var gap = 100;

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y+winHeight >= top+ height+gap && y+winHeight<=footerTop) {

    // if so, ad the fixed class
    $('.leftsidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top',winHeight-height-gap +'px');
    }
    else if (y+winHeight>footerTop) {

    // if so, add the fixed class
    $('.leftsidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top',footerTop-height-y-gap+'px');
    }
    else
    {
    // otherwise remove it
  $('.leftsidebar').removeClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top','315px');
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Just put that `if($(window).width() > 1025)` inside the function provided to the scroll event. It helps if you correctly indent your code ;)

Comment: You should use `window.matchMedia()` instead of checking for `$(window).width()` which can be inconsistent. BTW, your code is no more relevant for jq 2.x, `$.browser` has been removed from jq 1.9 and anyway supporting msie6 doesn't really no more make sense

Comment: @A. Wolff IE6 still make sense(but with a big pain) for financial area...

Comment: @Maris Ya it could make sense but i don't think OP is developping for a financial institution. And btw, his jsFiddle is using jq 2.x version which anyway doesn't support IE6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var flag = false;
// This will keep on checking for window size while you are scrolling.
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if (flag){
        // Do whatever you want here
        alert("hey");
    }
});

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1025){
        flag = true;
    } else {
        flag = false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I do it in a resize() event instead?

Comment: I need the code to work on scroll but to only work when equal to or above 1025px. Changing scroll to resize seems to break this.

Comment: also need to trigger resize on page load to set flag properly ...just chain `.resize()` after event handler

Comment: @user2498890: Updated the code. Now it will check for width on resize and your code will work only if the width of screen is more than 1025. Also add a similar check for "onload" event.

Comment: @charlietfl: Yep. added that in the comment.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I'll have to keep trying and let you know how I get on. Thanks for your help though. I can get the window.load to work but the resize one just isn't working.

Comment: @user2498890: when you say that resize isn't working, can you check whether the code inside resize is getting called or not. Try using an alert. Or maybe just create a very simple prototype in jsfiddle which shows your problem. Will try to fix that.

Comment: I've just added an alert so I know that the resize is working because it detects when the screen is at different sizes. It's hard for me to create a fiddle due to everything going on in my site. When I inspect the element on lower screen width it is showing the 'leftsidebarfixed' classes as active which is why I thought it was the resize not working. I'm not sure if its something else conflicting or if its the JS I've shown you. Sorry this is so complicated!

Comment: @user2498890: See this fiddle i created using your example only. http://jsfiddle.net/bf5kfL0s/   Have added the width check for 600px so that you can see it in the fiddle. Resize the viewing part of fiddle to see that when your width is more that 600px the javascript works else it just behaves as only the HTML and css should.

Comment: Thanks  for the fiddle I can't argue that your code doesn't work because I know it does I'm just struggling to find out whats causing mine to be stuck where its not supposed to. It's definitely something I'm doing wrong somewhere else. Thanks for all your help though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/). The $.browser function was removed in jQuery 1.9. This can end up in serious problems in your code.

Just add something like the follwing code in the first if condition:

```
if (!msie6 && $('.leftsidebar').offset()!=null && $(window).width() > 1025 ) {
    ...
}
```

That should be all. If you want, that javascript should react on window resize just add something like the following

```
$(window).on('resize', function( event ) { /* code here */ }).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wasn't aware so thanks for informing me. I tried your solution but when you resize the browser the element is just fixed. Is that what you mean by `$(window).on('resize'...`?

Comment: The short example with the resize event ment, that you should put your javascript code inside the event (where code here is mentioned). I added the trigger function so the code will be executed from start.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment: Just put that `if($(window).width() > 1025)` inside the function provided to the scroll event.

e.g.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y + winHeight >= top + height + gap && y + winHeight <= footerTop) {
            // if so, ad the fixed class
            $('.leftsidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', winHeight - height - gap + 'px');
        } else if (y + winHeight > footerTop) {
            // if so, ad the fixed class
            $('.leftsidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', footerTop - height - y - gap + 'px');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3w5dt/31/

### Notes:

- not that 1 PX matters, but you did say `> 1024px`, hence changing 1025 to `1024` :)

Comment: Surely if($(window).width() > 1024) or if($(window).width() => 1025) ?

Comment: @thecraighammond: Their code, not mine :) Have changed it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this and it works if i refresh the browser but if i resize the div is just getting stuck as position fixed. I need the code work when the screen size is more than or equal to 1025px.

Comment: haha, good point. Yeah @user2498890 you'll want to go with > 1024 to satisfy that. Not sure what you mean by getting stuck at position fixed?

Comment: Basically as the js is saying to add the class 'leftsidebarfixed' and therefore adding position fixed when you resize the browser the div is remaining in the position it was at above 1025 instead of becoming relative and sitting at the top where its supposed to.  I've been trying to implement mechanicals answer but can't get the resize to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(screen.width >= 1024)
{
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    //Write your function code here
   });
}
```

I hope it will help you.